# adding one second to a "timer" when a variable increases by 1

Tags: python

I have a variable that ranges from 0 to 300 based on some complicated conditions that aren't really relevant.

my problem is that I want to make a timer variable that increases like a clock would. when my variable increases by 1, I want the timer variable to increase by one second. I have this:

```
for timer in range(1,301):
    seconds = range(1,60)
    print seconds
```

the problem is that I need seconds to go from 0.59 to 1.00, not to 1.60 because that's not how time works. I'm thinking I need a minutes variable also and to add one to it once 'seconds' is > 59. but I'm not sure exactly how to go about this

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do.  As it stands, it is hard to tell what might work and what might not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that a minute is 60 seconds, so you could just count seconds and use the modulus operator `%`

```
seconds = 0
for timer in range(1,301):
    #whatever ...
    seconds += 1
    print seconds/60, seconds % 60
```